# Calling A function from multiple scripts in python

Tags: python, import

I'm trying to validate multiple functions from separate files all with the same names.

So, consider I have a directory of directories:
dir1
which has 
s1,s2,s3,...,sn which all are directories and each contain a file called submission.py. I do not know what s1 through sn are until run time.

In each submission.py, there's functions f1 through fm.

I would like to create a script that executes f1 through fm and prints their output for each s1 through sn's submission.py file.

I would like to think that I could import each submission.py file in each directory, but the problem is that each file has the same name. Also, s1 through sn is not known until run time. Obviously, I can determine s1 through sn using the os.listdir function.

Any idea on how I can call f1 from two different files after getting the names of the directories through os.listdir?

Comment: Do the subdirectories s1,s2,s3 etc each contain `__init__.py` files?

Comment: No. The subdirectories are actually intro student submission directories and they're just submitting simple scripts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible using [imp](https://docs.python.org/2/library/imp.html).

```
>>> import os, imp
>>> dirs = os.listdir('.')
>>> dirs
['s1', 's2']
>>> modules = {d: imp.load_source(d, d + '/submission.py') for d in dirs}
>>> modules
{'s1': <module 's1' from 's1/submission.py'>,
 's2': <module 's2' from 's2/submission.py'>}
```

Then, to call a function `f3` in the `submission.py` module contained in subdirectory `s2` for example, it would be:

```
modules['s2'].f3()
```

Comment: This solution is beautiful.